# Paperjs subtract path to shape not working properly

Tags: subtraction, paperjs

With Paperjs, I try to subtract a path from a circle, but it is not working as expected. Here is my code:

```
// Create circle
var c1 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
c1.fillColor = 'red';

// Create path
var eraser = new paper.Path({strokeColor: 'black', strokeWidth: 20, strokeCap: 'round'});
eraser.add(new paper.Point(20, 20)); 
eraser.add(new paper.Point(100, 80)); 
eraser.add(new paper.Point(150, 150)); 
eraser.fillColor = 'white';
eraser.opacity = 0.6;

// Subtract
result = c1.subtract(eraser);
result.selected = true;
result.opacity = 0.8;
result.fillColor = 'pink';
```

It seems the path is seen as a polygone, not lines when subtracted:

[image]

Here is a jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/785ergpy/35/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is because Paper.js do the boolean operation with the paths fill geometry, ignoring the stroke.
This is more obvious if you remove the stroke from your example (see this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/jVKxbsMgEP0VxGJbsgiOlDZK1aVeO1TK2HTA+KK4oYAO7Ciq+u89Y1d1pnYAcXqP97h3fHKrPoDv+P4MUZ94ybVrx3q1YjWCisB0h9rAAQ92UMh0xR6ZhQt7UfEk6oTlqXadjXklZcnuZVGyjSwexku6EsfOmNoZh3Q1Q2izBIzr18WT3I8HoAqAs49XHlCMbvkkOKFCtW2+wJP7mszXsviTl165/Q9xQ0Tabpk3/TSmh2yJOq90F6+ESXG37HTfNxGVjikVZ0NkCKE3kZgUUpjRfJKZDCeCCGBAR2iJGbGHJbR8i+2NWWKkZ4OhdKc+5oGMy6N7J0VBft0Az+qauopPrrdtyIcOLqJJZxG0ogFLsZ0joB/S0MTOfswn8N3r29c3)).

What you need to do, if you want to subtract the stroke, is turning it into a path first.
Unfortunately, Paper.js doesn't have this feature yet, even if it's planned for a long time and exist as an experimental version (see this [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371)).
So you have to either use this experimental feature or use a vectorial drawing software like Adobe Illustrator, and export your stroke path as SVG for example, before using it with Paper.js.